# Why am I getting null results?

Tags: php, mysql

So i have a very simple function that runs against a MySQL database of users with a few other credentials. I have written several other functions that run similar queries with that work as expected. However currently every time I run a query against my DB i get null result. I have taken the query itself and ran it directly against it(phpmyadmin) and was able to retrieve the desired results.

```
function getName( $user ){
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','*****','*****','*****');
    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        echo 'Failed to Connect: '. mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT firstName,lastName FROM users WHERE user=? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($fname,$lname);


    $stmt->fetch();

    $lArr = str_split($lname);
    $canName = $fname . ' ' . $lArr[0].'.';
    return $canName;
}
```

I have tried with and without limit just in case. var_dump always shows null. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: To ask the obvious, have you tried running the raw query against your MySQL instance, and do you get any records back?

Comment: Yes I have and yes I get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: You forgot to `->fetch()` any results from the result set, just binding them to variables is not enough

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but based on the comment by @RiggsFolly it looks like you have a PHP, rather than a MySQL, problem.

Comment: I will give this a shot. However in the past I have not needed fetch and have been able to get results. I'll report back soon with an answer.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: After using fetch() still returning null. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I hate to say RTFM, but really, this is very much the same as the first example on [Example #1 Object oriented style](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) so check that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `->fetch()` any results from the result set, just binding them to variables is not enough

```
function getName( $user ){
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','*****','*****','*****');
    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        echo 'Failed to Connect: '. mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT firstName,lastName FROM users WHERE user=? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($fname,$lname);

    // now fetch data into the bound variables
    $stmt->fetch();

    $lArr = str_split($lname);
    $canName = $fname . ' ' . $lArr[0].'.';
    return $canName;
}
```

Comment: So I'm marking fetch() as the answer. However while I found i did in fact need to use fetch(), I also found I had to use double quotes instead of singles. With fetch still null with fetch and double quotes was able to return what I needed. As always thank you for everyone's help.

Comment: Double quotes were required where?

Comment: Oh and you didn't mark this as the answer? But never mind

Comment: Double quotes were required around my sql statement and in the bind_param statement. I've never ran into this before. My understanding is that php is intentionally syntactically sweet and should not see to much of a difference in single quotes vs double.

Comment: It is. Are you missing a quote somewhere above this. i.e. an unclosed string literal

Answer (score -1):

You execute the query but you are not picking up the results (As RiggsFolly was saying). You shout use fetch() of fetchall()

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Sorry Misha, but this is **not an answer** its a comment, and one that has already been made, with an answer already posted. You nearly have enough rep to make comments, so dont risk getting down votes for a non-answer answer

Comment: Also he is using `mysqli_` so a link to a PDO method is not really very helpful!